# Ignore rows with blank values while importing a CSV in rails application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, import

I have an app where I allow users to import CSV data.

Everything was working until users started importing data with blank rows in the CSV file. I am using the following to grab the rows out of the CSV file:

```
CSV.readlines(import_file, headers: true, skip_blanks: true)
```

I thought that if I added the option to skip_blanks that it would do that but it hasn't. Any ideas on how I can ignore the blank rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the users are supplying empty rows, CSV files could be very funny at times

Comment: please try this form: `CSV.new( ( open import_file ), headers: true, skip_blanks: true ).readlines`

Comment: @majioa I just tried that but still has blank lines. I looped through the result and still have four empty rows that show up like this, ',,,'

Comment: You should avoid using .new on ruby IO objects except you are certain to close it, so it's better you use .open instead, readlines delegates to read which calls open and calls new  view source here https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/01b1f004618b67f2e3033e055cb3a87f05fd3fa6/lib/csv.rb#L1324-L1331

Comment: @GrahamJackson those rows are not empty ',,,,' is four comma separated values

Comment: @GrahamJackson just posted a working code below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work

```
CSV.open(import_file, skip_blanks: true).reject { |row| row.all?(&:nil?) }
```

### EDIT

You requested for readlines, it calls open in the CSV source code in the end but this is it:

```
CSV.readlines(import_file, skip_blanks: true).reject { |row| row.all?(&:nil?) }
```

I feel open would perform better though I have not done any bench marking

```
CSV.open(import_file, skip_blanks: true, headers: true).reject { |row| row.to_hash.values.all?(&:nil?) }

CSV.readlines(import_file, skip_blanks: true, headers: true).reject { |row| row.to_hash.values.all?(&:nil?) }
```

The above returns a collection of CSV::Row objects

Comment: This is a good answer but is there anyway to do the same thing but use readlines instead. (I would prefer to stick to that because the csv importer depends on the format that readlines provides the data in).

Comment: @GrahamJackson updated the answer to use readlines as you requested, if this works can you upvote and accept the answer?

Comment: Thank you for the help. This doesn't solve my problem but I appreciate it and will up vote it because it may help someone else. I need to remove the null values but still return a CSV object. This solution will return an array.

Comment: @GrahamJackson let me modify more, so you have your csv objects

Comment: Thank you. The new solution you provided does provide a collection of csv objects but doesn't end up removing the rows with nil values.

Comment: @GrahamJackson well with my test csv it does remove it, I need to catch some sleep, I hope I have helped :-)

Comment: Ok, so I figured out how to get the results back as an array of CSV objects thanks to your solution. Something like this: 'CSV.readlines(import_file, skip_blanks:true, headers:true).reject {|row| row.to_hash.values.all?(&:nil?)}'

Comment: Can the .reject block be used and also return a CSV::Table object?  I've been playing around with this and it always returns an array.

Answer (score 10):

This returns a CSV::Table object.

`CSV.parse(import_file, headers: true, skip_blanks: true).delete_if { |row| row.to_hash.values.all?(&:blank?) }`

Comment: the `blank?` was a nice solution for me, then works for  '', ' ' and nil row data

Answer (score 4):

The solution depends on if you read the CSV with or without headers, and if you want to keep working with a `CSV::Table` object or if you are happy with an array of `CSV::Row`

Without headers you'll get rows that looks something like:

```
[#<CSV::Row nil nil nil]
```

With headers:

```
[#<CSV::Row "name":nil "abbreviation":nil "age":nil]
```

**SOLUTION**

Without headers and return array of CSV::Row

```
table.reject { |row| row.all?(&:nil?) }
```

Without headers and return CSV::Table

```
table.delete_if { |row| row.to_hash.values.all?(&:nil?) }
```

With headers and return array of CSV::Row

```
table.reject { |row| row.to_hash.values.all?(&:nil?) }
```

Without headers and return CSV::Table

```
table.delete_if { |row| row.to_hash.values.all?(&:nil?) }
```

**FURTHER READING**

Ruby Documentation for [delete_if](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html#method-i-delete_if)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I managed remove blank lines from csv:

```
table = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: true)
table.delete_if { |row| row.to_hash.values.all?(&:blank?) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to filter out columns that include just whitespaces use:

```
row.all? { |column| column.nil? || column.strip.empty? }
```